# How to display the camera preview in Unity using MediaCapture class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, media, capture

How can I display the camera preview (what camera sees) in Unity using the MediaCapture class? 
I know that it is possible in a UWP app by creating a CaptureElement in the xaml page and set the source of this element.
But, is possible to create an object like CaptureElement in Unity? Or either how can I display the preview of the camera using MediaCapture class?

Thank you!

Comment: When you ask the *"is it possible questions"*, what exactly do you expect as an answer? Let's say it is possible and I put an answer that says *"it is possible"*....How does that help you? You know it is possible so do a re-research then ask a question with a code.

Comment: The recommended way to do this is through Direct3D. Use the UWP C++ API to create the texture then use `IDirect3DBaseTexture9` on D3D9, or `ID3D11ShaderResourceView` on D3D11 to hold the Texture so that you can access it on Unity's side through pointers by creating/updating Texture with `Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture` and `Texture2D.UpdateExternalTexture`.  This should get you started.